# Access violation on combobox clear

Tags: arrays, delphi, combobox, delphi-xe8

I am using Delphi XE8 to write a client/server application which can access multiple databases.

As part of the settings form, a TComboBoxEx is used to display and select from a dynamic array of records which hold information each database and two buttons are used to add or remove records from the array.

The array is saved and loaded to/from a single formatted string, the name property of each record being used as the title for each combobox item.

On form show and on either add or remove database button presses an update procedure is called which first clear and reloads the array and then repopulates the combobox.

```
procedure TSettingsForm.UpdateDatabaseCombo;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  LoadDatabaseList; // Clears and reloads databaselist dynamic array.

  with dbCombo.Items do
  begin
    BeginUpdate;
    if Length(DatabaseList) <> 0 then
    begin
      Clear;    // This section works fine.
      for i := 0 to High(DatabaseList) do
      begin
        Add(DatabaseList[i].dbName);
        dbCombo.ItemsEx[i].ImageIndex := 17;
      end;
    end;

    if (Length(DatabaseList) < 1) and (Count <> 0) then
    begin
      Clear;  // Access violation on this line.
    end;
    EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

The procedure works well on initial loading of the array on startup, even when no records have been saved, and when new records are added.
However the problem occurs during the removal of records, or shall I say updating the combobox after a record has been removed (there is no problem with the records removal from the data base list).

If there is more than on record stored in the array everything works fine, the combobox is cleared and repopulated. If however the record being removed is the last stored, ie index 0, as stated earlier the record is removed from the array as expected but the combobox update procedure throws the error `Access violation at address 0040B2D2 in module ***** Read of address FFFFFFE7` when the clear method is called. After which the combobox items list is clear but the text of the last selected item remains.

I have tried many different approaches to resolve this problem, the closes to success being to use the delete item method,

```
Delete(dbCombo.ItemIndex);
```

This again clears the final item from the combobox, without an exception, but the text still remains.

Please could anyone help with this problem and maybe point out the simple little thing that I am missing.

---

`Addition........`

As requested, here is the updated code for the `UpdateDatabaseCombo` routine,

```
procedure TSettingsForm.UpdateDatabaseCombo;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  LoadDatabaseList; // Clears and reloads databaselist dynamic array.

  if dbCombo.Items.Count <> 0 then
    dbCombo.Items.Clear;

  with dbCombo.Items do
  begin
    BeginUpdate;
    if Length(DatabaseList) <> 0 then
    begin
      for i := 0 to High(DatabaseList) do
      begin
        Add(DatabaseList[i].dbName);
        dbCombo.ItemsEx[i].ImageIndex := 17;
      end;
    end;
    EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

I have noted that if the call to `items.clear` is made without checking that the `items.count` value is more that 0 and exception is raised every time the routine is called, with the count check in place the exception is only raised when the last item in the combobox is being removed.

I have also added the routine for deleting a record from the array,

```
procedure TSettingsForm.DBRemoveButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ALength: Cardinal;
  i: Cardinal;
begin
  ALength := Length(DatabaseList);
  Assert(ALength > 0);
  Assert(dbCombo.ItemIndex < ALength);
  for i := dbCombo.ItemIndex + 1 to ALength - 1 do
    DatabaseList[i - 1] := DatabaseList[i];
  SetLength(DatabaseList, ALength - 1);
  SaveDatabaseList;
  UpdateDatabaseCombo; 
  if dbCombo.Items.Count <> 0 then
    dbCombo.ItemIndex := 0;
end;
```

An exception also occurs anywhere in the program if `clear` is called when the combobox is empty.

Comment: Get rid of the `with` statement, use `dbCombo.Items` for each property instead, and then use the debugger to figure out what's wrong. This is one more example of the bad things that can happen when you use `with` in your code. It makes problems hard to spot and debugging impossible (at least until you do the right thing and eliminate the use of `with`).

Comment: Thanks @Ken for your reply but in this case you are wrong in that the problem is not with the `with` loop, to prove this I removed the second `if` statement replacing with `if dbCombo.Items.Count <> 0 then dbCombo.Items.Clear`  immediately after loading the array but the result is still the same exception  error. ps sorry about the last comment, pressed enter by mistake.

Comment: @KenWhite is not wrong: you should avoid the use of "with" regardless.  Anyway, I suspect your problem lies in something you're not showing us. Calling dbCombo.Items.Clear twice should not result in an AV.  Please add to your q the code by which you add and remove records from your DatabaseList.

Comment: @Ken, please forgive me, I was not saying that you were wrong about the use of `with`, I was simply stating that in this instance it is not the cause of the problem, anyway I have now updated the question to provide more information.

Comment: I think you should try and enable "use debug dcu" in your configuration. Then run. Then use the call stack to figure out where the exception exactly happens when calling combobox  clear.

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to you all for your help. I have finally tracked down the problem,

`'God I feel so silly'`.

The culprit was in the `OnChange` event handler where I had placed a instruction to fill an edit box from the databases record password property, which would change automatically when a database is selected from the combobox.

The problem was that I had not added a conditional statement to check if there were any items in the database list to load from, and therefore when there weren't an exception was raised.

Two days wasted over a simple `if` statement. I have not done any real programming for a few years, I have really missed those pull your hair out moments.

Again, many thanks.